# calculator for programmer

Tags: 14.04, calculator

I've launched the calculator in my Ubuntu V14.04. I must do some hexadecimal calculations. But I don't know how to switch from the standard calculator to calculator for programmers? Any advise is very much appreciated. Thanks in advance. Erhard.

Answer (score 2):

Isn't it as simple as:
Navigate to the menu, click `Mode` and then choose `Programming` ?

Comment: no, the default programming calculator lacks a ton of features, like negatives, floating points, etc